# Preloading images over WiFi from New York Times app for Android?

Tags: applications, news-and-weather

I've set the NYTimes app to download over WiFi twice a day.  But it just downloads the articles, not the pictures.  So if I'm out and about, I either get no pictures or I burn cellular data.

How can I get this app to download the pictures over (free for me) WiFi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an option as of app version 6.10 to preload images.

[image: NYTimes App Image Preload]

However it only preloads some images, leaving you at risk of using a fairly substantial chunk of data simply by flipping though sections in the app.  As of this writing, there seems no better option.

Feedback to the Times is accepted at android@nytimes.com